# E guitar pickup problem

Tags: pick-ups

I have an old Luxor Les Paul guitar(inherited) I am getting very low output on the B and high E strings on both pickups , I have raised the pickups, but still the same low output. Any suggestions would be appreciated. (the strings are new)

Comment: Was that the reason for changing strings? Sometimes new strings aren't as good as they should be - but it's rare.

Comment: check your tone control. The tone knob(s) remove high frequencies, so if you have a reduction on both pickups on the high strings, the tone may be rolled all the way off, or there may be a malfunction with the Pot.

Comment: Old POTs (potentiometers) can build up a thin layer of corrosion. One quick way to remove some of this corrosion is to actuate the control through its full range of motion several times to clean the contact a little. Worth trying if the guitar has sat for a while.

Comment: In addition to Yorick's suggestion, there is also "contact cleaner", made specifically to help break up and sweep away this layer of corrosion. Formulations vary, most are a mix of isopropanol with some other highly volatile organic solvents (so yeah, I'd recommend opening a window and setting up a box fan to help exhaust the fumes from your workroom). These definitely help a lot, but simple mechanical action of the pot is often all it takes for mild cases.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys, I have tried all the advice given here,. I changed the strings because the were rusty, to Ernie ball’s ,the same as the ones on my Maton MS2000, I sprayed the potis with contact spray, I even turned one of the pickups around to see if perhaps there was a problem with the windings or magnets, No difference! The pickups are actually pretty good, It’s just the B and E that is the problem. Really weird. I’ve never come across this type of problem before, I’ve even replaced a few pickups over the years , so I am not exactly a novice, but this one has got me beat...

Comment: DId you test the cable and amp with a different guitar to verify the problem is inside this guitar?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. The tailpiece was rusty in the B and E  string holes, stoping a good earth. I cleaned and gently filed out the rust, put in a little oil, and now the good old Luxor plays like a dream, I’ve never had a problem like this before, But one is never too old to learn something new. Thanks to all the members for your suggestion and help. Nev.

Comment: I'm skeptical about this -- grounding the strings might prevent hum or noise, but the pickup acts purely on the physical motion of the metal string  relative to the magnet in the pickup.   So either cleaning out the tailpiece removed a major damping effect on the string, or you ended up actually fixing a ground connection to the pickups.

Comment: I can conceive of a situation where string damping or lack of sustain may be described or perceived as a volume problem. I also wonder about grounding, as anything simply flying past the pickup that can affect the field around a pickup will induce current.

Comment: @Yorik my apologies - for some reason your comment wasn't visible when I posted basically the same thing

Comment: @CarlWitthoft no apology needed. Not totally clear, but when I wrote "I also wonder" I meant that I was referring to your comment.